# How to generate and upload checksums with maven deploy plugin 3.0.0-M1?

Tags: maven, checksum, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-install-plugin

The feature to generate checksums seems to have moved from install to deploy plugin (see [MDEPLOY-231](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEPLOY-231)). There seems to be no parameter to control the generation and the deployment of checksums any more, neither in [install plugin 3.0.0-M1](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) (the "createChecksum" parameter apparently doesn't exist any more), nor in [deploy plugin 3.0.0-M1](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html).

I was assuming checksums would be activated by default now (see this [blog post](https://blogs.apache.org/maven/entry/apache-maven-deploy-plugin-version)), but I end up without any checksum neither in my local repo nor in Artifactory and I cannot see anything checksum-related in the logs (running mvn deploy).

It shouldn't be important, but maybe it is: I am using https transport, not ssh.

Here a log excerpt:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) @ base-module ---

[INFO] Installing C:\data\src\s-libs\base\target\base-module-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar to (...)
[INFO] Installing C:\data\src\s-libs\base\pom.xml to (...)
[INFO] Installing C:\data\src\s-libs\base\target\base-module-0.2.5-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to (...)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy) @ base-module ---
Downloading (...)
Uploading to psys_mvn: https://psys.ex1.de/artifactory/psys_mvn/de/ex1/psys/base-module/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/base-module-0.2.5-20200311.190843-3.jar
(...)
Uploading to psys_mvn: https://psys.ex1.de/artifactory/psys_mvn/de/ex1/psys/base-module/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/base-module-0.2.5-20200311.190843-3.pom
(...)
Uploading to psys_mvn: https://psys.ex1.de/artifactory/psys_mvn/de/ex1/psys/base-module/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/base-module-0.2.5-20200311.190843-3-sources.jar
(...)
Uploading to psys_mvn: https://psys.ex1.de/artifactory/psys_mvn/de/ex1/psys/base-module/0.2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
(...)
Uploading to psys_mvn: https://psys.ex1.de/artifactory/psys_mvn/de/ex1/psys/base-module/maven-metadata.xml
(...)
```

Comment: Are you using both maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin with version 3.0.0-M1 .. ? Please show a log of your build...

Comment: Yes, both 3.0.0-M1. My current logs contain confidential information. I'll try to reproduce that in an example project that can be published.

Comment: Are both plugins called within your build (see log file)....are you using a usual maven build or do you use things like maven tycho (OSGi)?  Special configuration for maven-install/maven-deploy?

Comment: I use Windows, toolchains and https. Apart from that it should be quite non-special.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I got exactly the same problem, but with a Nexus repository, using maven-install-plugin and maven-deploy-plugin version 3.1.1. No checksum whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `createChecksum` has been removed  and is documented on this page: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/index.html furthermore only during `mvn deploy` the checksums will be created and uploaded to remote repository. Checksums are activated automatically. There is no other action needed. If you use `mvn clean deploy` the checksum must be in your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository` like this:

```
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  11 khmarbaise  staff   352 Mar 11 19:01 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 khmarbaise  staff   224 Mar 11 19:01 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff   196 Mar 11 19:01 _remote.repositories
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff   698 Mar 11 19:01 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff   762 Mar 11 19:01 maven-metadata-snapshots.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff    40 Mar 11 19:01 maven-metadata-snapshots.xml.sha1
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff   195 Mar 11 19:01 resolver-status.properties
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff  2185 Mar 11 19:01 sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff    32 Mar 11 19:01 sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.md5
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff    40 Mar 11 19:01 sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r--   1 khmarbaise  staff  2149 Mar 11 18:55 sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

The upload shown in the picture is from a Nexus repository manager.

[image: Uploaded data with checksume]

Comment: I have no checksums at all - neither locally nor remote (Artifactory). Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like you are not using the same version of both plugins...? but a log file would help here...Or an example project which can reproduce the behaviour...

Comment: I added a log excerpt. Anything I should look for in debug logs?